# Best map format for open world 3d enviroment

Tags: c++, 3d, game-engine, ogre

I am making an open world 3d platformer in Ogre3D, and I have no idea on what kind of 3d map file format I should use for it.

I want to make low-polygon blocky-style objects. Probably rectangles and other geometrical figures that don't have circular edges. Some of those blocks will have properties, like climbable or they might move.

I was wondering what would be the best thing to do to make the map without recurring to making a map format and a map editor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at this: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/DotScene

Ogre 3d has it's own .scene format. You probably want to do it in this format.

Comment: Looks nice. Is there an editor for it? Because I have other people working on this project, and I would like them to make the map for me and I would do all the programming

Comment: http://www.ogre3d.org/tikiwiki/tiki-index.php?page=DCC%20Tools#Level_design

Comment: Thanks, I will look into it. I started with Ogre not so long ago

Comment: Just a note: DotScene is a library provided by the OGRE community, in fact OGRE doesn't provide anything for the scene management (import and export).